# post_excerpt instead of post_content, outside of the loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get a wordpress excerpt from a page to appear in a styled area of my footer. I currently have the following, which gives me the title and all of the content:

```
<?php
$page_id = 2;
$page_data = get_page( $page_id );
$content = $page_data->post_content;
$title = $page_data->post_title;
echo '<h3>'. $page_data->post_title .'</h3>';
echo '<p>'. $page_data->post_content .'</p>'; ?>
```

I've tried various combinations of post_excerpt instead of post_content, and have tried emulating and editing the example here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page but am not having any luck. A few times I've tried examples from other people, but there has been no content at all.

Could this be because I'm trying to get it to display outside of the loop, or have I just not hit the right combination yet?

Thanks.

Comment: what is the issue? are the page title and content not displayed ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why don't you just limit the string using [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)?

```
$content = $page_data->post_content;
$excerpt = substr($content, 0, 155);
```

something to that effect

at that rate, you don't need to try and find the true variable of the excerpt, and you can control the length, and whether or not it has ellipses at the end, etc.

Also, if you NEED to find the excerpt variables, you could just do a `var_dump($page_data)`, and see what returns the value you need, no?

**EDIT:**

you could try adding a manual excerpt to the pages using a function like this in functions.php

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_add_excerpts_to_pages' );
function my_add_excerpts_to_pages() {
    add_post_type_support( 'page', 'excerpt' );
}
```

**EDIT on an EDIT:**

So I just dug a little deeper, and this little guy right here might help you out. Drop this in your functions.php file ([source](http://wordpress.mfields.org/2010/excerpts-for-pages-in-wordpress-3-0/))

```
add_post_type_support( 'page', 'excerpt' );
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That solution works, and with several height limited boxes at the bottom, this might be the better solution, however, it does the control away from the end user (who won't be able to modify this setting).

My bigger problem is that the excerpt is being returned blank (see comments on previous answer), discovered using `<pre><?php print_r($page_data); ?></pre>`

Comment: You could always create a Options page with a drop down or text box. Creating a page is simple enough, and there's tons of tutorials, as well as a walkthrough in the codex. then you could just do something like this `$excerpt = substr($content, 0, get_option('excerpt_length', 'options-page');`

Comment: I modified my answer - a code like that at the bottom will add an excerpt metabox in your page editor. You could put manual excerpts in there and see if those return with a value?

Comment: Modified again with another snippet that might work as another alternative to get the value to return with something

Comment: Thanks for all of the digging. I've tried both suggestions, but no luck. That link talks about enabling as of WP 3.0, but it seems the more recent versions have broken this functionality. I'll have another look later, but I might just go with your first suggestion, as it'll let me keep all 3 columns a uniform height.

Comment: Hey Alex; I've just had another go with a fresh wordpress installation (same version, not sure how I managed to break it) but `add_post_type_support( 'page', 'excerpt' );` worked. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try resetting the wordpress query by putting this directly before the code you posted.

```
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: That's just a guess though... the WP docs make it sound like `get_page()` is perfectly suited to be used outside the loop.

Comment: I've tried that, with $page_data->post_excerpt instead of $page_data->post_content, but I still only have the title. What should I have to display the excerpt?

Comment: To debug, you could also try echoing the entire `$page_data` object to see if the content / excerpt properties exist or are just empty. Try putting this after your code: `<pre><?php print_r($page_data); ?></pre>` and see what it outputs.

Comment: Thanks coryetzkorn, that's useful. It seems that my problem is that the excerpt is blank, although, I can't see why it would be (I've added the 'read more' tag into the page in question).

Comment: Ok that's helpful to know. It sounds like `$page_data->post_excerpt` is definitely the right way to output the excerpt, but something else is preventing it from returning. Are excerpts working elsewhere on your site? A plugin or something in functions.php could be interfering.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for Excerpt...

```
<?php query_posts('cat=ID'.'&showposts=NO. OF POST') ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
<p><?php echo substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0,65).' [...]'; ?></p>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More...</a>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php endif;?>
```